# How to remove header from global karate-config.js file file

Tags: api, automated-tests, config, karate

I have written this code(see below) to set global headers value in karate-config.js file so that i don't need to write again and again in any feature file. That part is working fine.

But i want to remove one set of key value pair from my headers so that i can test the negative scenario of headers.

For example - I need to remove eid key and value from one of my scenario in feature file.

Like I have one feature file which contains 10 scenario and one of the scenario i want to pass header with one key value pair is removed. How can we achieve in karate.

Thanks in advance.

karate.configure('headers', { Accept: 'application/json', eid: 123, intVal: 557 });

Comment: If i am not using any karate.feature file instead i am using this below, so how to fetch key from the below code in feature file?? -karate.configure('headers', { Accept: 'application/json', eid: 123, intVal: 557 });